# Associate File with Wine Program on Mac

Tags: macos, file-association

I'm working on a Mac OS 10.13 computer and have Wine working great. Unfortunately when I try to permanently associate a file type with a program running in Wine I can not determine where to find it in Finder / how I would create the association? I can change the association just fine for regular non-Wine programs.

How do I associate a file type in Mac OS with a Wine-based program?